# Sqoop's import-all-table is not working

Tags: oracle, sqoop, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

Hi i am trying to import all table from all schema from Oracle DB to HDFS.

**This is my script:**

sqoop-import-all-tables -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://x.jceks --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521/yyyy --username xxxx --password xxxx --warehouse-dir /data-warehouse/xxxx --as-avrodatafile --compression-codec snappy --autoreset-to-one-mapper

When i am running this script, not getting any error and no any Job is starting.

**Output:**

```
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
find: failed to restore initial working directory: Permission denied
18/08/11 08:32:51 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running **Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.2.0-205**
18/08/11 08:32:51 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/08/11 08:32:51 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
18/08/11 08:32:51 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
18/08/11 08:32:53 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to IST
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user configured in sqoop does not have enough privileges to query and export the data from Oracle. Please check connect and query from command line to Oracle database.

Regards !!!

Comment: Hi @juamd, I am able to import single table by using this command:
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://x.jceks --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521/yyyy --username xxx --password xxxx --table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME --delete-target-dir --warehouse-dir /data-warehouse/direct1 -m 1 --as-avrodatafile --compression-codec snappy --fields-terminated-by '\001'
So i don't think there is any privilege issue.